# How to scroll up through Instagram direct messages using Selenium and Python with Chrome Device Toolbar

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, instagram, chromium

I'm trying to automate the scrolling on Instagram's Direct to be able to get to the beginning of an Instagram chat. Also I think that is not possible to select the scroll bar using xpath, so maybe is necessary to use an automatic key-pressing loop with the "home" key or "page up". But honestly I dont really know how to do this. Ps: If you keep the "home" key pressed you only will be able to scroll up a few pages before the scrolling just stops, so you need to release the key after a couple of seconds to keep scrolling up. So maybe this is not the best way to do what I'm looking for.
I hope somebody can help me, thank you very much!

Source Code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    from secrets import username, pw


    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    mobile_emulation = {

        "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },

        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }

    chrome_options = Options()

    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)




    class MsgBot:
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)

    self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
    sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
    sleep(5)
    login_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div/label/input')
    login_input.send_keys(username)
    pw_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div/label/input')
    pw_input.send_keys(pw)
    login_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[7]/button').click()
    sleep(4)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/button').click()
    sleep(4)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]').click()
    sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav[1]/div/div/header/div/div[2]/a/div').click()
    sleep(4)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]').click()
    sleep(4)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a').click()
    sleep(3)
    #scroll should begin
```

MsgBot()

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling to the element you can use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

to scroll to element using JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that currently works for me for scrolling the chat up to the beginning (implying that you are already on direct messages page):

```py
def scroll_to_chat_start(driver: WebDriver) -> list:
    # Wait until chat is loaded
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'VUU41')))

    # Set initial scroll y
    scroll_y = __scroll_position(driver)

    # Scroll until beginning
    while scroll_y != 0:
        __scroll_to_top(driver)
        # Wait for loader to show and hide
        loader_xpath = '//div[@style="height: 72px;"]'
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, loader_xpath)))
        while True:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until_not(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, loader_xpath)))
            except:
                break
        # Set new scroll y
        scroll_y = __scroll_position(driver)
        print('to reach top: ', scroll_y)

    message_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="listbox"]')

    return message_boxes


def __scroll_position(driver: WebDriver) -> int:
    return driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('div[class="JiVIq _0NM_B"]')
    .firstChild.firstChild.scrollTop''')


def __scroll_to_top(driver: WebDriver):
    driver.execute_script('''document.querySelector('div[class="JiVIq _0NM_B"]')
    .firstChild.firstChild.scrollTo(0,0)''')
```

Keep in mind that this may not work forever since the used class names are auto-generated and any major update might change them.